# Override style of dynamic iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use a 3rd-party javascript library (I'll just refer to it as "the jslib") in my web page that, when a certain link is clicked, dynamically generates and displays an iframe on my page. I am trying to override some styles on the iframe. In some cases I can do it, but in 1 case I cannot. Take a look:

[image]

Notice that my `border` style (lower, inside styles.css line 22) is being overridden by the jslib's `border` style of "0".

Here is the jslib reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js"></script>
```

I have tried the following approaches:

- I placed the style in my css file as you see above.
- I placed my css file below the jslib's reference in my page, hoping to override those styles.
- I placed the style inside a `<style></style>` block directly in my html page.

The jslib has no css file and no inline styles. All styles are built from within the js file that I reference in my page.

Is there a way with plain css to override that border style somehow? If not, there must be some way with jquery. But if I attempt it with jquery, I wouldn't know how to hook in to the jslib. Or if I try to hook into the link click that triggers everything, jquery may try to apply the style before the iframe has been created, etc. Not sure about where to hook, how to hook, and the timing of object creation.

What is the best approach to do this? Plain old CSS would be awesome, but if that's not possible, jquery styling would be welcomed.

Comment: If the iframe is not same domain you can't access anything inside it, can only affect the outer iframe element itself

Comment: but you can always style its "outside"

Comment: right, use `!important` to override border around iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a better specified selector like:

```
body #PPDGFrame .panel iframe {
   /* Your style here */
   border: 2px solid #666;
}
```

I prefer to avoid using important, you will end up in a important hell, this is due to [**selector priorities**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

So what do i mean by *selector priorities* - lets make a small example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap" class="wrap">
            <div class="element"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you have HTML as above, then you need to select the "div.element" you can do it very simple.

```
.element { /* some style */ }
```

How did paypal do it, they inject a inline stylesheet which had a id selector which is stronger than a class selector

```
#wrap .element { /* some style */ }
```

So how to overwrite this, you simple make a "stronger" selector

```
body #wrap .element { /* some style */ }
```

I prefer to use bem syntax on my classes to use "lightest versions of selectors", read more about BEM-syntax **[here](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/)**

If you need to do stuff after the content in the Iframe has been loaded, you will need to check for a callback in "the jslib" that your using and when it returns you'll do stuff

**Why not use !important**

In my opinion i pref to use it as a debugger tool instead of a production tool, i rarely use it to overwrite some javascript set style, which i also think is wrong when you can set a class that can hold the style instead.

If you end up having 5 or 10 similar selectors with *!important* on it starts to get confusing.

Comment: Simon, your approach works, but I don't understand how it did the override without using '!important'. It seems the original 3rd party style would have taken precedence as was happening to me originally. (The side effect still exists, but maybe I'll have to create a new question for that.)

Comment: @SweatCoder its basically just to make a stronger or more specified selector - i will edit my answer and elaborate

Comment: @SweatCoder His solution adds more weight to it. The most specific a selector is, the higher its priority is. By adding `body` before the exact same selector that jslib uses, it increases its weight enough to make it more important. `!important` simply and brutishly makes it more important through an exception.

Comment: Jaw.sh, thanks for the elaboration, it makes sense to me now. And of course, thank you Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`border: 2px solid #666 !important;`

The important flag prioritizes it over all other definitions, except other `!important` definitions.

Comment: more details about selector priorities: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Jaw.sh, that worked, but has a side effect. It forces the border to display around the iframe while the 3rd-party content is still loaded in the iframe, which I don't want. I didn't know this would occur until I tried your suggestion. In the final step of flow (going on inside iframe), the 3rd-party lib redirects the contents of the iframe to MY contents (a separate web page which I control). It is at THIS step that I want my border style to be invoked (once my page loads inside the iframe). Is there any way to delay the application of that style until this final step?

Comment: try to use the same selector than used by your lib: `#PPDGFrame .panel iframe`. Or if it is still does not, there is may be a kind of `ready` class used.

Comment: @SweatCoder What @Gael said. If your iframe contains 3rd party content, there is no way for you to know if that content has loaded due to cross-domain scripting rules. If it's hosted on your server and the library provides a reaction to the iframe loading, you can use that. You can also try to add a `[src]` attribute selector, like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/qLqo6spv/). This won't add the border until after a source is specified, but it will add it before the content is entirely loaded.